# Checkbox not checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Good day, I'm trying to clear a form depends on `checkbox changes`. It's working fine with the `clear form` . But the probem is my checkbox isn't checked. Any solution with that ? thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#general").change(function() {
    $('.form-horizontal').trigger("reset");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="group-border">
  <legend class="group-border">Form</legend>
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Transaction No</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" readonly required autocomplete="off" name="shippingno" id="shippingdoc" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input id="general" type="checkbox">General
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Reference</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="shippingno" id="shippingdoc" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-submit" id="reference" type="button">...</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Document No</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="docno" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Since your checkbox is inside the form, I assume that when you check it, it's also been reset.

Comment: @choz so, maybe i need create a hidden field which is save the checkbox value ?

Comment: why would it stay checked if you reset the form?

Comment: @YVS1102 If your hidden field is also in the form, I am afraid it will also gets reset..

Comment: @choz i'll remove the checkbox from the `form`. will it help?

Comment: @YVS1102 Why would you reset the form with a checkbox in the first place again?

Comment: @choz because i want to add ajax request on `#reference`

Comment: @YVS1102 I still don't understand. But if you insist using this approach, try my answer.

Comment: @choz my english hard to understand. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this, you can also set the value back again after you reset the form.

```
$(function () {
    $("#general").on('change', function () {
        var $cb = $(this),
            isChecked = $cb.prop('checked');

        $('.form-horizontal').trigger("reset");

        $cb.prop('checked', isChecked);
    })
})
```

Comment: it's working thanks. so i need set the checkbox value in variable first, right ?

Comment: @YVS1102 Yeah. There's lots of way, this is just one of them.